# Parsing Nested JSON Objects using Volley

Tags: android, json, parsing, object

I had gone through most of the answers in stack overflow and tried some of the answers which didn't work.

It is a response from a SOAP API.

I tried by using

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray heroArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject one = obj.getJSONObject("getProjectDetailsResult");
JSONObject two = one.getJSONObject("NewDataSet");
heroArray= two.getJSONArray("Rec");

for (int i = 0; i < heroArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject heroObject = heroArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Hero hero = new Hero(heroObject.getString("decProjectID"), 
heroObject.getString("chvProjectNameEng"));
```

This is what I am getting in the LogCat

```
2019-12-08 15:00:47.572 6134-6134/net.marvelheroes W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"decProjectID":"100300230049","intProjectSlNo":"49",......"percentage":"0"} at Rec of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
2019-12-08 15:00:47.572 6134-6134/net.marvelheroes W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
2019-12-08 15:00:47.572 6134-6134/net.marvelheroes W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:588)
```

I tried

```
JSONObject heroArray = new JSONObject();
JSONObject one = obj.getJSONObject("getProjectDetailsResult");
JSONObject two = one.getJSONObject("NewDataSet");
heroArray= two.getJSONObject("Rec");
```

But I am getting error for the rest of the code. I am testing this with the sample from https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-fetch-json/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rec` is not `JSONArray`, it's `JSONObject`. Try using

```
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject one = obj.getJSONObject("getProjectDetailsResult");
    JSONObject two = one.getJSONObject("NewDataSet");

    if(two.get("Rec") instanceof JSONArray) {

        JSONArray heroArray = two.getJSONArray("Rec");

        for (int i = 0; i < heroArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject heroObject = heroArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Hero hero = new Hero(heroObject.getString("decProjectID"),
                heroObject.getString("intProjectSlNo"),
                heroObject.getString("chvProjectName"),
                heroObject.getString("chvProjectNameEng"),
                heroObject.getString("chrProjCatCode"),
                heroObject.getString("chvEngProjCategory"),
                heroObject.getString("nchvSecType"),
                heroObject.getString("chvEngSecType"),
                heroObject.getString("chvImplOfficerDesg"),
                heroObject.getString("chvImplOfficerDesgEng"),
                heroObject.getString("singleYrAmt"),
                heroObject.getString("TotExp"),
                heroObject.getString("percentage"));

            heroList.add(hero);
        }
    } else {
        JSONObject heroObject = two.getJSONObject("Rec");

        Hero hero = new Hero(heroObject.getString("decProjectID"),
            heroObject.getString("intProjectSlNo"),
            heroObject.getString("chvProjectName"),
            heroObject.getString("chvProjectNameEng"),
            heroObject.getString("chrProjCatCode"),
            heroObject.getString("chvEngProjCategory"),
            heroObject.getString("nchvSecType"),
            heroObject.getString("chvEngSecType"),
            heroObject.getString("chvImplOfficerDesg"),
            heroObject.getString("chvImplOfficerDesgEng"),
            heroObject.getString("singleYrAmt"),
            heroObject.getString("TotExp"),
            heroObject.getString("percentage"));

        heroList.add(hero);
    }
} catch ( Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: how do I iterate through the objects?

Comment: No need to iterate. It's give u `Hero`

Comment: And the property inside `Rec` is different. So you have to update your `Hero` model. Can you post your `Hero` model?

Comment: @JayanDev, have you got it?

Comment: I was trying to do it using Iterator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203842/discussion-between-jayan-dev-and-md-asaduzzaman).

Comment: I need a small help.