# Do something after volley request is processed

Tags: android, parsing, android-listview, android-volley, android-adapter

I was working on parsing the nested JSON objects using Volley and I got the answer from the stackoverflow itself.

[Parsing Nested JSON Objects using Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234730/parsing-nested-json-objects-using-volley)

But I think the code can be optimized without the if else and also I have to display a text "No Data" if the volley request is null or no data received. I tried to check using `adapter.isEmpty`, `adapter.getCount()`

None of it worked.

This is my code

```
datalist=false;
      progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        schemeslist=false;
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONObject one = obj.getJSONObject("getProjectDetailsResult");
                            JSONObject two = one.getJSONObject("NewDataSet");

                            if(two.get("Rec") instanceof JSONArray) {
                                datalist=true;
                                JSONArray heroArray = two.getJSONArray("Rec");

                                for (int i = 0; i < heroArray.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject heroObject = heroArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    APIModel hero = new APIModel(heroObject.getString("decProjectID"),
                                            heroObject.getString("intProjectSlNo"),
                                            heroObject.getString("chvProjectName"),
                                            heroObject.getString("chvProjectNameEng"),
                                            heroObject.getString("chrProjCatCode"),
                                            heroObject.getString("chvEngProjCategory"),
                                            heroObject.getString("nchvSecType"),
                                            heroObject.getString("chvEngSecType"),
                                            heroObject.getString("chvImplOfficerDesg"),
                                            heroObject.getString("chvImplOfficerDesgEng"),
                                            heroObject.getString("singleYrAmt"),
                                            heroObject.getString("TotExp"),
                                            heroObject.getString("percentage"));

                                    heroList.add(hero);

                                }
                            } else {
                                datalist=true;
                                JSONObject heroObject = two.getJSONObject("Rec");
                                APIModel hero = new APIModel(heroObject.getString("decProjectID"),
                                        heroObject.getString("intProjectSlNo"),
                                        heroObject.getString("chvProjectName"),
                                        heroObject.getString("chvProjectNameEng"),
                                        heroObject.getString("chrProjCatCode"),
                                        heroObject.getString("chvEngProjCategory"),
                                        heroObject.getString("nchvSecType"),
                                        heroObject.getString("chvEngSecType"),
                                        heroObject.getString("chvImplOfficerDesg"),
                                        heroObject.getString("chvImplOfficerDesgEng"),
                                        heroObject.getString("singleYrAmt"),
                                        heroObject.getString("TotExp"),
                                        heroObject.getString("percentage"));

                                heroList.add(hero);

                            }


                            ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(heroList, getApplicationContext());

//adding the adapter to listview

                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + listView.getAdapter().getCount(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if(!datalist){
            txtNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

//creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

//adding the string request to request queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Can anyone tell me where should I put the if condition to work?
I checked with a toast for getting item count, but if there is no data, it is displaying blank and not 0. So I am not able to check

Answer (score 0):

You can check  `size()` of `data list(heroList)`, `size()` is `zero` means you have `no data`.

try this

```
if(heroList.size() == 0){
     txtNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: No use. Actually there is no data in any of these functions when no data is received.